# Vue 3 V-Model Passing to Grandchild Component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vee-validate

I have three components that I would like to pass a reactive model down through from the parent -> child -> grandchild (vee-validate Field).

So parent component would look like:

```
<template>
  <child v-model="formData" />
</template>
.
.
.
setup() {
  const formData = ref<CreateAccount>({
      email: "",
      firstName: "",
      lastName: ""
  });

  return {
    formData,
  };
}
```

Child component (with grandchild component) looks like:

```
<template>
  <Field
    type="text"
    name="email"
    v-model="modelValue.email" ????
  />
</template>

export default defineComponent({
    name: "step-2",
    components: {
      Field,
    },
    props: {
      modelValue: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
      },
    },
    emits: ["update:modelValue"],
  },
});
```

Now my issue is that I cannot just pass modelValue to the Field v-model prop, so I'm not sure if there is a chain of events or restructuring the child modelValue that needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the following solution in my child component:

```
<template>
  <Field
    type="text"
    name="email"
    v-model="model.email"
  />
</template>

export default defineComponent({
  name: "step-2",
  components: {
    Field,
  },
  props: {
    modelValue: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    model: {
      get() {
        return this.modelValue;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$emit("update:modelValue", value);
      },
    },
  },
},
});
```

Comment: It's not the most straightforward but acceptable solution. This is what this composable actually does, https://vueuse.org/core/usevmodel/ . Also there's an inconsistency here, a child receives the whole data but emits only email part. Depending on your case you may need to use custom events instead of update:modelValue if you need to merge email, etc values to data object

Comment: @EstusFlask I guess I wasn't clear in my initial write up, but there are other <Field> components in the child component that utilize other properties of that object as well (formData.firstName, formData.lastName, etc)

Comment: Then you will have problems with your current approach. I updated my post to reflect this

Answer (score 1):

When a child is a passthrough component, desugared syntax can be used instead of `v-model` to pass data in both directions:

```
  <child v-model="formData.email" />
```

and

```
  <Field
    type="text"
    name="email"
    :modelValue="modelValue"
    @update:modelValue="$emit("update:modelValue", $event)"
  />
```

In case there are multiple fields to update, it may be more convenient to go away from `v-model` convention in a child and a parent and use own event to patch parent state:

```
  <Field
    type="text"
    name="email"
    :modelValue="formData.email"
    @update:modelValue="$emit('updateFormData', { email: $event })"
  />
```

Then in a parent `Object.assign(formData, event)` is performed on `updateFormData`.